# How to delete credential from commit in github repo?

Tags: git, github

I have accidentally committed my credential in my GitHub repo.

I have to delete this credential(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, secret access) from here otherwise my account will be suspended. I have deleted the credential from my account now but it is exposed in the previous commit.

Comment: As long as you have revoken the credentials, you are ok.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove sensitive files and their commits from Git history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove from your **git history** with two steps. Merge/Edit/remove commit and force push. Details below

1. Merge those two commits into one

   ```
   git rebase -i head~20   //I used 20 based on your repo. Some number greater than your two commits which you want to merge
   ```

   It will open the interactive screen like below[image]
   Here change **pick** to **squash** to merge the commit with the previous commit. In your case change is at line 6. You can **drop/edit commits** also

   Then save and quit (:wq) and which will ask for `new commit message` for the combined commits. Edit, save and quit.
2. It will show the message like *Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
   and have 15 and 16 different commits each, respectively.* (less than 1 for 1 squash)
3. Do **force** push `git push -f`